Flutter: How to make PhotoViewGallery photos cover overlaid widgets when zooming
I'm building a newspaper app, and want to have a gallery function to display all the images in an article, being able to scroll between them and zoom in as desired, with overlaid information being covered by the image as you zoom in.
I'm currently using the PhotoViewGallery package. However, I want to overlay a photo index indicator right above the top right of every photo, as well as caption/credit text at the bottom of the screen.
My issue is that when zooming in on a photo, the overlaid text does not get covered, but stays visible and in place as I zoom in. I cannot put them under the PhotoViewGallery.builder in the stack, since the Gallery creates a black background that would then cover the information I'm trying to overlay.
Any thoughts on how to achieve this functionality?
I have tried using ExpandedPageView and then adding zoom functionality to each photo individually with PhotoView, but then I run into the issue of infinite sizing of the PhotoView widgets, since I am using CachedNetworkImage and do not know the size of images before creating the gallery.
I have also tried using the zoom_pinch_overlay package with ExpandedPageView, but the gesture detection is too slow, and conflicts with the ExpandedPageView, so it works technically but it is cumbersome to interact with as a user.
This is using photo_view ^0.15.0.
Here is the relevant code:
class ZoomableImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initialIndex;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> images;

  const ZoomableImage({super.key, required this.images, required this.initialIndex});

  @override
  State<ZoomableImage> createState() => _ZoomableImageState();
}

class _ZoomableImageState extends State<ZoomableImage> {
  
  late int currentIndex;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentIndex = widget.initialIndex;
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black, // set background color to black
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          // reset status bar when exiting
          SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
            statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          ));
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            PhotoViewGallery.builder(
              itemCount: widget.images.length,
              builder: (context, index) {
                return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                  imageProvider: CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.images[index]['link']),
                  minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
                  maxScale: 1.0,
                  initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
                  heroAttributes: PhotoViewHeroAttributes(tag: widget.images[index]['link']),
                  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Icon(Icons.error),
                );
              },
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
              pageController: PageController(initialPage: currentIndex),
              scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              loadingBuilder: (context, event) => Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: event == null
                      ? null
                      : event.cumulativeBytesLoaded / event.expectedTotalBytes!,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            // photo index indicator
            if (widget.images.length > 1)
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                top: 266, // TODO: device specify!
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(deviceWidth/56.1, deviceWidth/78.54, deviceWidth/56.1, deviceWidth/78.54),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.66),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "${currentIndex + 1}/${widget.images.length}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: deviceWidth/32.725, color: Colors.white, letterSpacing: deviceWidth/231, fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              
            // caption and credit
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  if (widget.images[currentIndex]['caption'] != 'NO_IMAGE_CAPTION' &&
                      widget.images[currentIndex]['caption']!.isNotEmpty)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        widget.images[currentIndex]['caption']!,
                        maxLines: 10,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13.5, 
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                      
                    if (widget.images[currentIndex]['credit'] != 'NO_IMAGE_CREDIT' &&
                        widget.images[currentIndex]['credit']!.isNotEmpty)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 5, 12, 0), 
                        child: Text(
                          widget.images[currentIndex]['credit']!,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 10,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12, 
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ]
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks so much in advance.

I have just a little thought. Maybe you can use PhotoViewScaleStateController to do that. The controller has the outputScaleStateStream property which can watch the updates of size, so you can hide the indicator when the scale value is more than 1.

Thanks so much, this works very well. Pasting the implementation below for reference.

As per cj0x39e's suggestion, the approach of using PhotoViewScaleStateController to control if the overlays are shown or not works well. This is how I did it:
class ZoomableImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initialIndex;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> images;

  const ZoomableImage({super.key, required this.images, required this.initialIndex});

  @override
  State<ZoomableImage> createState() => _ZoomableImageState();
}

class _ZoomableImageState extends State<ZoomableImage> {
  
  late int currentIndex;
  bool isZooming = false;
  late PhotoViewScaleStateController scaleStateController;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentIndex = widget.initialIndex;
    scaleStateController = PhotoViewScaleStateController();
    StreamSubscription scaleStateSubscription = scaleStateController.outputScaleStateStream.listen(_onScaleStateChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scaleStateController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onScaleStateChange(PhotoViewScaleState scaleStateData) {
    setState(() {
      if (scaleStateData.isScaleStateZooming){
        isZooming = true;
      }
      if (scaleStateController.scaleState == PhotoViewScaleState.initial) {
        isZooming = false;
      }
      else if (scaleStateController.scaleState != PhotoViewScaleState.initial) {
        isZooming = true;
      }
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black, // set background color to black
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          // reset status bar when exiting
          SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
            statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          ));
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            PhotoViewGallery.builder(
              itemCount: widget.images.length,
              builder: (context, index) {
                return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                  imageProvider: CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.images[index]['link']),
                  minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
                  maxScale: 1.0,
                  initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
                  heroAttributes: PhotoViewHeroAttributes(tag: widget.images[index]['link']),
                  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Icon(Icons.error),
                  scaleStateController: scaleStateController,
                );
              },
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  currentIndex = index;
                  isZooming = false;
                });
              },
              pageController: PageController(initialPage: currentIndex),
              scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              loadingBuilder: (context, event) => Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: event == null
                      ? null
                      : event.cumulativeBytesLoaded / event.expectedTotalBytes!,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            // photo index indicator
            if (widget.images.length > 1)
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                top: 266, // TODO: device specify!
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: isZooming ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(deviceWidth/56.1, deviceWidth/78.54, deviceWidth/56.1, deviceWidth/78.54),
                    child: Text(
                      "${currentIndex + 1}/${widget.images.length}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: deviceWidth/32.725, color: Colors.white, letterSpacing: deviceWidth/231, fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              
            // caption and credit
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: isZooming ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    if (widget.images[currentIndex]['caption'] != 'NO_IMAGE_CAPTION' &&
                        widget.images[currentIndex]['caption']!.isNotEmpty)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0), // TODO: here too
                        child: Text(
                          widget.images[currentIndex]['caption']!,
                          maxLines: 10,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13.5, // TODO: here too
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                        
                      if (widget.images[currentIndex]['credit'] != 'NO_IMAGE_CREDIT' &&
                          widget.images[currentIndex]['credit']!.isNotEmpty)
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 5, 12, 0), // TODO: here too
                          child: Text(
                            widget.images[currentIndex]['credit']!,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 10,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12, // TODO: here too
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

